# angular show and hide function

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have created a show and function using Angular. At the moment i have the basics working. When the user hovers over tile the class is added and removed.

```
<article class="col-sm-6" ng-mouseenter="showHiddenTile()" ng-mouseleave="hideHiddenTile()">                
    <div class="grid-block--img">
        <img src="/assets/homepage/home-tile5.png">
        <div class="grid-headings">
            <h2>a new<br/>home for<br/>whiskey</h2>
            <p><span class="heading--bold">WORK.</b><span>&nbsp;Food and Beverage Design<
        </div>
        <div class="grid-block-hidden" ng-class="{isVisble: tileBlock}">My overlay</div>
   </div>
</article>
```

I want to use this show and hide function multiple times throughout the site. At the moment when I hover over one of the elements it adds the isActive class to all elements instead of individually.

Angular code

```
// SHOW AND HIDE FUNCTION
  $scope.showHiddenTile = function() {
  $scope.tileBlock = true;
}

$scope.hideHiddenTile = function() {
  $scope.tileBlock = false;
}
```

How can I target the isVisble class individually?

Comment: Why don't you use `ng-show` and `ng-hide` ?

Comment: I want create a transition using css

Comment: cant get you. explain some more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have an array

```
$scope.array = [];
```

push it to array when mouseenter event

```
function showMethod(element){
    $scope.array.push(element);
}
```

slice it from array when mouseleave event

```
function hideMethod(element){
    $scope.array.slice($scope.array.indexOf(element),1);    
}
```

use this condition in ng-class

```
ng-class="array['blockName'] != -1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
<article class="col-sm-6" ng-mouseenter="showHiddenTile('block-id')" ng-mouseleave="hideHiddenTile('block-id')">
```

And:

```
   $scope.showHiddenTile = function(blockId) {
     $scope.tileBlock[blockId] = true;
    }

   $scope.hideHiddenTile = function(blockId) {
    $scope.tileBlock[blockId] = false;
   }

   $scope.isShowTitle = function(blockId) {
    return $scope.tileBlock[blockId];
   }
```

And:

```
<div class="grid-block-hidden" ng-class="{isVisble: isShowTitle('block-id'}">My overlay</div>
```

And then have a unique block-id per article.

Answer (score 0):

why not have 2 styles

```
.grid-block-hidden{
    //style when mouse is not on 
}

grid-block-hidden:hover{
   //style on hover  
   //isVisble class
}
```